# Contact Form 7 datepicker - date format not working for other language than english

Tags: wordpress, datepicker, contact-form-7, date-formatting

I have the Contact Form Datepicker plugin installed (version 2.6.0) and a simple contact form like this:

```
[date date-508 id:date-508 date-format:dd.mm.yy]
```

Date format dd.mm.yy is showing correctly only in english.

Once I change the page to any other language it displays like: dd/mm/yy:
01/11/2018

I have WPML 4.0.8.
The datepicker window is translated to other languages but the format of selected date is wrong.

Any idea how to debug this? 
What's causing this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question on wordpress.stackexchange.com or even better you better in the wordpress.org repository of contact form 7.

Answer (score 0):

Found that the Contact Form 7 datepicker loads regional settings from external files like this:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/i18n/datepicker-fr.min.js
These files contain a dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy" that alter the datepicker declared format.

I modified the contact-form-7-datepicker.php to load the files from local storage.
Of course I had to download them and change the dateFormat in them.

So the change looks like this:

```
public static function enqueue_js() {
        $regional = CF7_DateTimePicker::get_regional_match();
        $proto = is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http';

        if (! empty($regional)) {
            wp_enqueue_script(
                'jquery-ui-' . $regional,
                plugins_url('js/i18n/datepicker-' . $regional . '.min.js', __FILE__),  // Gabriel - to change format date in input
                // $proto . '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/' . self::JQUERYUI_VERSION . '/i18n/datepicker-' . $regional . '.min.js',  // original code
                array('jquery-ui-datepicker'),
                self::JQUERYUI_VERSION,
                true
            );
```

That's not the best solution as a future update will overwrite the php file.

I would prefer a javascript function that will override the dateFormat again but nothing worked.